# c# Windows Phone 8.1 html size smaller than WebView size

Tags: c#, html, webview, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I have a wp 8.1 application with a WebView control which loads a html file located in the Assets folder, therefore bundled in the package.

The WebView control has the size set to width=320 and height=50. 
The html contains a div set to width=320px, height=50px.

Now comes the fun part: the rendered html is much smaller than the actual WebView size as seen in the below picture.

**Question(s):**

1. Why is this happening? Is it related to viewport or scale? If yes, how can I fix it?
2. How should I fix this so the html fits the WebView size?

PS: The below html is the simplest I have for demo purposes. In the real world I request the html size from an API, and the API gives me the formatted html, and I have no control on the html. The purpose of all this is to display html ads coming from an ad network API.

PS2: this happens on both wp 8.1 and 10 emulators, and on my lumia 925 win 10 as well.

Here is a code snippet from the **xaml page**:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestWebview.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestWebview"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebView Name="webview" Width="320" Height="50"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click">Load me</Button>
</Grid>
```

Here is the **code behind**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace TestWebview
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/index.html"));
            Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            webview.NavigateToString(content);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the content of **index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#test{
    width:320px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a **screenshot** of the emulator:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the viewport size. Try adding this to your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Reference: [Controlling the viewport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462082(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ViewportSettings)

Comment: This seems to work, but only if I modify the html manually. However, as I mentioned above, I do not have control of the html that I display there. I assume that I must use InvokeScriptAsync to add the meta tag, but I cannot make it work. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @ciprian You could use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) to download webpage as string. Then combine the string with `<meta/> `. After that call [NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx) to show the combined page in webview.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I was able to do so, and it works. The html looks something like:

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I was able to do so, and it works. The html looks something like: `<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /></head><body><div>..html content from third party ...</div></html>`. The problem is now I am not able to click on a link inside the div. This doesn't seem to be a c#/wp problem, but more a javascript one (capturing events). I tried creating a html file with the above structure, and the behavior is the same in any browser I tried. Any hints on this one?